# Android Button shown differently when run

Tags: android, xml

What the title says when I design the button on XML it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j21qb.png)
But in the actual application, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQoQX.png)

I expect that when running the app it looks like the XML design at first I though it was because the style wasn't being recognized but that's not the case in other button works just fine

Here's the XML for a better look

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:padding="20dp"
        tools:context="com.fia2.presentation.tos.application.item.six.fragments.PreSignNotificationFragment">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_ic_confirmation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_confirmation"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:text="@string/signature_welcome_title"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_ic_confirmation" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:text="@string/signature_welcome_subtitle"
            android:textColor="@color/colorMediumGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_description" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_start_sign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/test_background"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
            android:drawableTint="@color/color_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="328dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_in_log_in"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Post the actual xml.  We can't tell anything without that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create a drawable with the content like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/your_color" />

</shape>
```

and set it as the background of your Button.

PS. In case the Button doesn't change the color when you set a new background, you may try to replace it with the `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton`